# Combine select statements with php and sort by time

Tags: php

So I have 5 separate select statements.

```
<?
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table5 WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```

I need to combine all the results, organize all the results based on time with the newest time first, and then echo a message based on which table the result came from.

Note each table has a row time.

Example results:

```
<p>This result was posted 5 minutes ago and came from table 2</p>
<p>This result was posted 10 minutes ago and came from table 5</p>
<p>This result was posted 1 day 6 hours ago and came from table 1</p>
<p>This result was posted 2 weeks ago and came from table 3</p>
<p>This result was posted 3 weeks ago and came from table 1</p>
```

**UPDATES:**

Selecting * is an absolute requirement, which is why using mysql is not a viable solution. Mysql can't do full table joins, and instead mirrors the practice by doing cross joins of the tables. However if you understand the woe's of cross joins, you will understand when I say some of these tables will return thousands of results for a user, making cross joins not viable as cross joins will create countless duplicate rows for each entry, and having thousands of entries makes for millions and tens of millions of rows when doing a cross join. PHP seems to be the only solution.

I need a solution that wil use php to combine the selects and sort them based on time NOT a mysql solution.

Comment: I'm still hoping for a valid solution that actually solves the question I asked. , which is using php to sort the values and echo results, NOT using sql to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new column in each table to hold the tablename. And then this kind of query can solve your problem:

> SELECT username,timestamp,tableName from table1 union 
>          select username,timestamp,tableName from table2 order by 2 desc

Comment: There was a reason I was using fetchAll and *, doing 5 table unions isn't practical in this instance because the data would end up returning millions of results if I do. The reason I am seeking a php solution is because mysql has flaws with doing full table joins and actually can't do a full table join. Instead it does a cross join, which ends up resulting in countless dozens of duplicate results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem should be solved where it belongs. This is obviously a db problem. 
But as you have other concerns then you can try first fetching all rows from tables to an array. All tables should be selected with an order by descending timestamp field. Define a pointer for every table which shows the newest item in the related table. In your loop find the newest record amongst the rows which these pointers pointing to. and increase this pointer after printing out the info. Hope it helps. Here is an example:

```
            $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE username = :username order by timestamp desc');
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $user);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row[0] = $stmt->fetchAll();

            $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE username = :username order by timestamp desc');
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $user);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row[1] = $stmt->fetchAll();
            // table lengts
            $table_len[0]=sizeof($row[0]);
            $table_len[1]=sizeof($row[1]);
            //initialize every table pointers to 0 
            $table_pointer[0]=0;
            $table_pointer[1]=0;

            while ($table_pointer[0]<$table_len[0] || 
                   $table_pointer[1]<$table_len[1]){
                // find the newest time
                $time1=strtotime($row[0][$table_pointer[0]]['timestamp']);
                $time2=strtotime($row[1][$table_pointer[1]]['timestamp']);
                $tableWithNewestTime=findNewestTime($table_len,$table_pointer,$time1,$time2);

                $timeDif=time()-strtotime($row[$tableWithNewestTime][$table_pointer[$tableWithNewestTime]]['timestamp']);
                echo "This result was posted ".$timeDif." s ego and posted from table".($tableWithNewestTime+1)."<br>";
                // increase the table pointer
                $table_pointer[$tableWithNewestTime]=$table_pointer[$tableWithNewestTime]+1;
            }

            function findNewestTime(array $table_len, array $table_pointer, $time1,$time2){
                    if ($table_pointer[0]>=$table_len[0])
                        return 1;
                    if ($table_pointer[1]>=$table_len[1])
                        return 0;
                    if($time1<$time2)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return 0;
            }
```

Comment: I was actually contemplating using nested foreach loops. Running each query as an array, nest the loops of each array, then do an if table1[time] > table2[time] && table3[time] && table4[time] && table5[time] {} else if table2[time] > ..... etc.

Comment: Nested loops wouldn't be efficient. If you know the complexity concepts my advice would cost you about O(maxTableLength) while nested loops would cost you O(t1*t2*t3*t4) where each t represents the number of rows of the related table.

Comment: Not only that, my way doesn't give me the desired effect, as an if statement will display one or the other not actually display in order based on time. Will be attempting you way today :)